# vb6/vba ado LEFT JOIN ON a range of dates

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, vb6

I have a main table (T1) with 3 columns: Product, Qty, PurchaseDate

For example :

```
MouseFX, 13, 24/12/2015
```

Then a secondary table (T2) with 3 columns: Product, UnitPrice, FromDate.

The same product may have more than one row in T2 according to when the UnitPrice has been updated:-

```
MouseFX, 12$, 24/12/2013
MouseFX, 13$, 23/1/2014
MouseFX, 15$, 2/3/2018
```

For a specific product (`'MouseFX`'), I need to retrieve the `UnitPrice` from `T2` with :

```
PurchaseDate (24/12/2015) > FromDate(23/1/2014) 
AND PurchaseDate< FromDate(2/3/2018)
```

I assume that it should be done with a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.UnitPrice from T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON PurchaseDate ?????/?
```

I wish I could post some code but don't have any idea. In Excel/VBA I would have used Vlookup with the fourth parameter # 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT T1.*,
       (SELECT TOP (1) T2.UnitPrice 
        FROM t2
        WHERE t2.product = t1.product AND
              t2.FromDate <= t1.PurchaseDate
        ORDER BY t1.FromDate DESC
       ) as T2.UnitPrice
FROM T1;
```

It is common practice to include a `ToDate` in the second table so it is a type-2 dimension where you can use `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error after the 1st parenthesis (don't know why?), but it seems also that the code will always pick the last UnitPrice from T2 while it could be in a row between the minimal and maximal DromDate

Comment: @user3387046 . . . I fixed the logic.  I don't know what the issue could be.  If you remove the parentheses around the `(1)`, does that fix the problem?